# MongoDB cannot remote connect to Mongod running on ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

This is the PC client, it has good connection to our ubuntu server, we can ping it and use filezilla and remote control it and everything, but we cannot connect to the mongod running on the ubuntu server

[image: This is the PC client, it has good connection to our ubuntu server, we can ping it and use filezilla and remote control it and everything, but we cannot connect to mongod running on the ubuntu server]

First we thought it was the firewall (read on stackoverflow that you had to add mongods port to the firewall, so we did).

[image]

We tried everything - reinstalling -  bind_ip = 10.5.50.16 port = 27017  and bind_ip = 0.0.0.0 port 27017  etc etc...

This is a completely fresh installation - what are we missing?

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution. In order to access mongodb from another machine, you must add 0.0.0.0 to the ip table of the server: "add port mongo". I hope this can help others who have similar problem with connecting.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/